# SQL index design regarding joins, filters, and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, join, indexing, db2, sql-order-by

I'm working on optimizing some queries for a DB2 LUW database and I'm going to restructure some existing indexes. However, I have a few questions on subjects that don't seem to be clearly defined, at least from what I've been able to find. For starters, here's a rundown on the query itself:

```
SELECT 
--About a dozen fields from TABLE A--
--A few fields from joined tables--
FROM
TABLE A
--A few inner join/left joins, mostly on A.ID1 and A.ID2, BIGINT generated keys--
WHERE
A.ONE = :x
AND A.TWO IN (:y)
AND A.THREE IN (--uncorrelated suquery--)
AND A.FOUR IS NULL
AND (A.FIVE BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2
OR
A.SIX = 'STUFF')
ORDER BY A.SEVEN
```

A few things of note:

- There is an index on A.ID1 and A.ID2 alone, likely a clustered index as this is the primary key
- There is an index on A.SEVEN
- I am revising the index on the rest of the fields in the WHERE clause

So all of the join/filter/order columns are indexed. The question is this: Should they all be combined into a single index or left separate? If I were to put A.SEVEN into the same index, would I still want to place it according to selectivity, or would that be irrelevant as there's no filtering with it, only sorting?

EDIT:
I find myself using an often-faster alternative to the OR clause, at least in the queries that I'm using:

```
CASE WHEN (first statement) THEN 1 
WHEN (second statement) THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END = 1
```

This has been surprisingly effective on some queries, but I'm not sure if/how it affects the use of indexes compared to the OR clause. In addition, would not the ONE through FOUR be best organized in order of selectivity, ie, if FOUR only has twelve distinct values and ONE has 10k, then ONE is best put at the front of the index.

Answer (score 0):

I am not intimately familiar with DB2s specific handling of indexes.  But assuming it is like other databases, I don't think you are going to be able to use an index for the final sort.

A good index on this query based on the `where` clause is `A(one, two, three, four)`.  After that, you are stuck between `five` and `six`, due to the `or` condition.  You can put either of these in to the index.  Putting both in probably won't make a difference -- only the first would be used with the second resolved by scanning through that portion of the index to find the rows that meet the other condition.

In other words, the utility of the index has ended before you get to `seven`.

If DB2 is really sophisticated, it might be able to take advantage of two indexes,  `A(one, two, three, four, five)` and  `A(one, two, three, four, six)`.  Once again, due to the `or` condition, the index will not help with the `order by`.

Because of the equality conditions, `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four` and go in any order in the index.  With one caveat.  I do not know how db2 treats the `in` condition with a subquery.  I'd be inclined to build the index on `A(one, two, four, three)`.

Comment: I've been able to excise the OR statement. See above.

Comment: @user1017413 . . . The `case` statement is semantically different, because the clauses impose an ordering.  That means that you would insert the variables in the index in the same order as in the `case` statement, assuming DB2 is smart enough to recognize this.

Comment: Nice. That's one step in the right direction. Now I need to determine where and how to put them together in the index. My kingdom for CREATE/DROP in the testing environment...

We've all learned one thing, though: OR clauses are evil.